# amazon-dynamodb and filtering by date

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table which has a GlobalSecondaryIndex with a date field as attribute of keytype "range". Values are stored in ISO-format "YYYY-MM-DD".
I want to access in node only records with dates greater than a certain date.
It seems to work with a parameter for my query:

```
KeyConditionExpression: 'myDate >= :myDate',
ExpressionAttributeValues: {   
    ':myDate': '2017-11-17'
}
```

However I do not quite understand. The date is technically speaking a string. Is it reliable to trust the string comparison or should it be done in a different way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can relay on this as long as the date is stored in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

DynamoDB doesn't have a separate data type for Date. Date can be stored either as String or Number.

```
Date    S (string type). The Date values are stored as ISO-8601 formatted strings.
```

**Storing date as String:-**

> You can use the string data type to represent a date or a time stamp.
>   One way to do this is by using ISO 8601 strings, as shown in these
>   examples:

- 2016-02-15
- 2015-12-21T17:42:34Z
- 20150311T122706Z

**Storing date as Number:-**

> You can use the number data type to represent a date or a time stamp.
>   One way to do this is by using epoch time—the number of seconds since
>   00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970. For example, the epoch time 1437136300
>   represents 12:31:40 UTC on 17 July 2015.

[Data types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html)

Comment: Ok, this I understood. But this myDate >= :myDate in my example is based on plain string comparison, right? Having two dates 2016-02-15 and 2016-02-14 the first one is greater because the last character "5" is greater than"4", right?

Comment: It seems like epoch time is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

use this approach for the date filter in the dynamoDb table, and it's working for me.

```
{
TableName: your-table-name ,
FilterExpression: '#attr2 BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date',
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#attr2': 'created_at',
},
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':start_date': `2021-04-01T00:00:00`,
      ':end_date': `2021-04-05T23:59:59`
}
```

I hope this will help for new to aws